# How to do type conversion with the Scala Camel DSL

Tags: scala, apache-camel

How can I do type conversion with the Camel Scala DSL?

In other words, what is the Scala DSL version of this Java DSL example:

```
from("file:/tmp/myfile").convertBodyTo(String.class).to("log:com.example")
```

Comment: To further illustrate, this is what I have without the type conversion: `"file:/tmp/myfile" --> "log:com.example"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of convertBodyTo you should use `as(...)` method.

If you try to find the mapping between Scala and Java DSL elements one of the useful places to take a look at in sources is SAbstractDefinition. This is how I found out the answer to your question because http://camel.apache.org/scala-dsl-eip.html only mentions `as` as part of another example (and doesn't say it's a replacement for convertBodyTo)

Comment: Great! So the complete scala DSL example ended up like this: `"file:/tmp/myfile" as(classOf[String]) "log:com.example"`

Comment: I logged a ticket to add convertBodyTo to the Scala DSL so its similar to all the other DSLs. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-5872

Comment: That would be nice, what will happen to 'as'?